# Windows 8 control in Windows 7 App

Tags: .net, windows-8, windows-7, combobox, controls

Is there a way to get the Windows 8 Combobox control to appear in an app running in Win 7 / XP?

This is the control I am talking about: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhny2.png

I want it to look the same across all platforms. Does anyone know of a way to accomplish this?